# Angular2 app architecture (web, mobile, native)

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, single-page-application, nativescript

Lets imagine an ng2 app which handles following platforms: web, mobile-web and mobile-native.

Owing to the fact there are many shared files (redux stuff like action creators, reducers..., services, common components), 
everything could be in one repository. In most cases there are differences between web, mobile-web and mobile-native view login in components and routing. 
Everything is managed by webpack which builds all stuff using .mobile.ts and .desktop.ts extensions. Files with .base.ts extensions contains shared view logic between desktop and mobile components.

Current (simplified) file structure is as follows (desktop is web version, mobile is mobile-web):

```
assets/
app/
    /common
        actions/
        enums/
        models/
        effects/
        pipes/
        reducers/
        services/
        components/
            account-list/
                account-item/
                    account-item.component.base.ts
                    account-item.component.desktop.ts
                    account-item.component.desktop.html
                    account-item.component.mobile.ts
                    account-item.component.mobile.html
                    index.ts
                account-list.component.base.ts
                account-list.component.desktop.ts
                account-list.component.desktop.html
                account-list.component.mobile.ts
                account-list.component.mobile.html
                index.ts 
    /modules
        /desktop
            /accounts
                accounts.component.desktop.ts
                accounts.component.desktop.html
                accounts.routes.desktop.ts
                index.ts
        /mobile
            /accounts
                accounts.component.mobile.ts
                accounts.component.mobile.html
                accounts.routes.mobile.ts
                index.ts
    app.component.desktop.ts
    app.component.mobile.ts
    app.module.desktop.ts 
    app.module.mobile.ts
    app.routes.desktop.ts
    app.routes.mobile.ts
```

As you can see, number of files is growing so fast. I dread to think how it could look by adding another native platform. Unfortunatelly I can't find any interesting examples for my case.

The only one that I've found is:
[Angular2 advanced seed link](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed-advanced)

But it seems preety weird and nonintuitive as well.

Do you have any advice how to make better structure for that case ? I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Have you tried to build an app with your suggestion of projectstructure? If so, would you recommend to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create different projects and create a common angular package, like this:

- **common** (include angular services and helpers)
- **web** (component and web-specific services/views)
- **mobile-web** (component and mobile web-specific services/views)
- **mobile-native** (component and native-specific services/views)

Maybe you can join web and mobile-app together. But this setup worked for me in many projects

Comment: how do you share the ressources between those projects? Do you copy the common-stuff into the other projects with watch-tasks? I like the idea of the projectstructure posted by @Donut because you don't need any jobs to share the ressources

Comment: you can create separate NPM packages for the shared components